# How to use a Chicken Scheme module in a separate directory?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── main.scm
└── stream
    ├── stream.import.scm
    ├── stream.scm
    └── stream.so
```

`stream.scm` defines a module:

```lisp
; stream.scm
(module stream
  (...)
  (import scheme (chicken base))
  ...)
```

and `main.scm` uses `stream` module:

```lisp
; main.scm
(import stream)
...
```

I compiled `stream` via `csc -s stream.scm -j stream`.
I’d like to compile the `main.scm` using the `stream` module nested in the `stream` directory, but I can’t find a way to do that.

I read the man page and I tried

```sh
csc main.scm -I ./stream
```

but it prompts a warning

```
Warning: the following extensions are not currently installed: stream
```

and the executable does not work:

```
Error: (require) cannot load extension: stream
...
```

It does work when I put `main.scm` in the `stream` directory.

What should I do to make `main.scm` aware of the `stream` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want to set `CHICKEN_REPOSITORY_PATH` for this project.

Example:

```
~/dev/scheme/subdir_test$ chicken-install -repository
/home/richardh/dev/chicken/lib/chicken/11

~/dev/scheme/subdir_test$ export CHICKEN_REPOSITORY_PATH="/home/richardh/dev/chicken/lib/chicken/11:/home/richardh/dev/scheme/subdir_test/sub/"
```

```
~/dev/scheme/subdir_test$ cat alpha.scm 
(import beta)

(print "Hello " (hello_name))
```

```
~/dev/scheme/subdir_test$ cat sub/beta.scm 
(module beta (hello_name)

  (import scheme)

  (define (hello_name)
    "World")
)
```

```
~/dev/scheme/subdir_test$ cd sub/
~/dev/scheme/subdir_test/sub$ csc -s beta.scm -j beta
```

```
~/dev/scheme/subdir_test/sub$ cd ..
~/dev/scheme/subdir_test$ csc alpha.scm 
~/dev/scheme/subdir_test$ ./alpha 
Hello World
```

If you google "chicken scheme virtualenv" you will find several examples of more sophisticated versions of this.

You might also be interested in the "chicken-belt" and "dust" eggs http://wiki.call-cc.org/chicken-projects/egg-index-5.html#tools if you want to have multiple versions of chicken itself installed.